# ¿Cómo puedo alinear las tres filas con las tres columnas finales usando fpdf?

Tags: php, pdf

tengo un reporte el cual funciona perfectamente pero el único problema es que quiero alinear las tres filas con las tres columnas finales de la derecha.

```
<?php
require('../pdf/fpdf.php');
require('../conexion/conexion.php');
$pdf =& new FPDF('P', 'mm', 'letter'); //para que la hoja sea tipo carta
$pdf->AddPage('P','letter'); //para que la hoja sea tipo carta
$pdf->Image('../logo/sat.png',20,8,40);
$pdf->Ln(25);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 20, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(220, 8, utf8_decode('LISTADO GENERAL TRANSFERENCIAS DIARIAS'), 10,8, 'C');
$pdf->Ln(5);
$pdf->SetFillColor(255,210,67);//Fondo verde de celda
$pdf->SetTextColor(3, 3, 3); //Letra color blanco
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 9);
$pdf->Cell(10, 5, utf8_decode ('N°'), 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Cell(30, 5, utf8_decode ('N° Transferencia'), 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Cell(40, 5, utf8_decode ('Nombres y Apellidos'), 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Cell(40, 5, utf8_decode ('Monto Transferido'), 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode ('Porcentaje'), 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode ('Ganancia'), 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode ('Total'), 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode ('Fecha'), 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Ln(5);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 9);

$consulta = $DB_con->query("SELECT 
transferencias.id_transferencias,
transferencias.n_transferencia,
transferencias.fecha,
transferencias.hora,
transferencias.monto_trasferido,
transferencias.porcentaje,
transferencias.ganancia,
transferencias.total,
transferencias.id_usuarios,
transferencias.id_bancos_admin,
transferencias.id_cuentas_admin,
transferencias.id_clientes,
transferencias.id_bancos,
transferencias.id_cuentas,
transferencias.portada,
transferencias.status,
clientes.id_clientes,
clientes.cedula,
clientes.nombres,
clientes.apellidos,
clientes.telefono,
bancos.id_bancos,
bancos.bancos,
usuarios.id_usuarios,
usuarios.user

           FROM transferencias 
                INNER JOIN clientes ON clientes.id_clientes=transferencias.id_clientes
                INNER JOIN bancos ON bancos.id_bancos=transferencias.id_bancos
                INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id_usuarios=transferencias.id_usuarios
                WHERE transferencias.fecha=CURDATE();");
if($consulta->rowCount() > 0){
$i=1;
$total_monto_trasferido = 0;
$total_ganancia = 0;
$total_total  = 0;



while ($linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{ 


$total_monto_trasferido = $total_monto_trasferido + 
$linea["monto_trasferido"];
$total_ganancia = $total_ganancia + $linea["ganancia"];
$total_total = $total_total + $linea["total"];

$pdf->Cell(10, 5, $i, 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Cell(30, 5, utf8_decode ($linea['n_transferencia']), 1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(40, 5, utf8_decode ($linea['nombres']." ".$linea['apellidos']), 1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(40, 5, utf8_decode ($linea['monto_trasferido']), 1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode ($linea['porcentaje']), 1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode ($linea['ganancia']), 1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode ($linea['total']), 1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode ($linea['fecha']), 1,0,'C');
$pdf->Ln();


 $i++;
}


$pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode ($total_monto_trasferido), 1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(80, 5, utf8_decode ($total_ganancia), 1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode ($total_total), 1,0,'C');




}else


echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel yellow darken-2 center'>
<h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
¡ Advertencia: No se ha encontrado ningún registro !
</h5>
</div>";

$pdf->SetY(10);
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->Ln(8);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 8);
$pdf->Cell(114,8,'',0);
for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++)
$pdf->Output('Reporte Transferencias Diarias.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

**mi problema esta aqui que es lo que quiero tratar de alinear**

```
$pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode ($total_monto_trasferido), 1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(80, 5, utf8_decode ($total_ganancia), 1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode ($total_total), 1,0,'C');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tienes que agregar una columna con el atributo cols-span de 5 y le eliminas los bordes ...

Comment: me podrias dar un ejemplo nos e trabajar muy bien con fpdf

Comment: simplemente agrega 5 cell vacios... ahora que recuerdo fpdf no acepta rowspam ni colspam por eso me pase a html2pdf jejejeje saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias amigo he conseguido la solucion

```
<?php
require('../pdf/fpdf.php');
require('../conexion/conexion.php');
$pdf =& new FPDF('L', 'mm', 'letter'); //para que la hoja sea tipo carta
$pdf->AddPage('L','letter'); //para que la hoja sea tipo carta
$pdf->Image('../logo/sat.png',20,8,40);
$pdf->Ln(25);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 20, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(220, 8, utf8_decode('LISTADO GENERAL TRANSFERENCIAS DIARIAS'), 10,8, 'C');
$pdf->Ln(5);
$pdf->SetFillColor(255,210,67);//Fondo verde de celda
$pdf->SetTextColor(3, 3, 3); //Letra color blanco
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 9);
$pdf->Cell(10, 5, utf8_decode ('N°'), 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode ('Fecha'), 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Cell(30, 5, utf8_decode ('N° Transferencia'), 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Cell(70, 5, utf8_decode ('Nombres y Apellidos'), 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode ('Porcentaje'), 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Cell(40, 5, utf8_decode ('Monto Transferido'), 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Cell(35, 5, utf8_decode ('Ganancia'), 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Cell(35, 5, utf8_decode ('Total'), 1,0,'C','R');

$pdf->Ln(5);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 9);

$consulta = $DB_con->query("SELECT 
transferencias.id_transferencias,
transferencias.n_transferencia,
transferencias.fecha,
transferencias.hora,
transferencias.monto_trasferido,
transferencias.porcentaje,
transferencias.ganancia,
transferencias.total,
transferencias.id_usuarios,
transferencias.id_bancos_admin,
transferencias.id_cuentas_admin,
transferencias.id_clientes,
transferencias.id_bancos,
transferencias.id_cuentas,
transferencias.portada,
transferencias.status,
clientes.id_clientes,
clientes.cedula,
clientes.nombres,
clientes.apellidos,
clientes.telefono,
bancos.id_bancos,
bancos.bancos,
usuarios.id_usuarios,
usuarios.user

          FROM transferencias 
                INNER JOIN clientes ON clientes.id_clientes=transferencias.id_clientes
                INNER JOIN bancos ON bancos.id_bancos=transferencias.id_bancos
                INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id_usuarios=transferencias.id_usuarios
                WHERE transferencias.fecha=CURDATE();");
 if($consulta->rowCount() > 0){
 $i=1;
 $total_monto_trasferido = 0;
 $total_ganancia = 0;
 $total_total  = 0;



 while ($linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
 { 


 $total_monto_trasferido = $total_monto_trasferido + 
 $linea["monto_trasferido"];
 $total_ganancia = $total_ganancia + $linea["ganancia"];
 $total_total = $total_total + $linea["total"];




 $pdf->Cell(10, 5, $i, 1,0,'C','R');
 $pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode ($linea['fecha']), 1,0,'C');
 $pdf->Cell(30, 5, utf8_decode ($linea['n_transferencia']), 1,0,'C');
 $pdf->Cell(70, 5, utf8_decode ($linea['nombres']." ".$linea['apellidos']), 1,0,'C');
 $pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode ($linea['porcentaje']), 1,0,'C');
 $pdf->Cell(40, 5, utf8_decode ($linea['monto_trasferido']), 1,0,'C');
 $pdf->Cell(35, 5, utf8_decode ($linea['ganancia']), 1,0,'C');
 $pdf->Cell(35, 5, utf8_decode ($linea['total']), 1,0,'C');
 $pdf->Ln();


 $i++;
 }

 $pdf->Cell(150, 5);  
 $pdf->Cell(40, 5, utf8_decode ('Total:'." ". $total_monto_trasferido), 1,0,'C');
 $pdf->Cell(35, 5, utf8_decode ('Total:'." ". $total_ganancia), 1,0,'C');
 $pdf->Cell(35, 5, utf8_decode ('Total:'." ". $total_total), 1,0,'C');




 }else


 echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel yellow darken-2 center'>
 <h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
 ¡ Advertencia: No se ha encontrado ningún registro !
 </h5>
 </div>";

 $pdf->SetY(10);
 $pdf->AliasNbPages();
 $pdf->Ln(8);
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 8);
 $pdf->Cell(114,8,'',0);
 for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++)
 $pdf->Output('Reporte Transferencias Diarias.pdf', 'I');
 ?>
```